# c# wpf how to freeze a ListBox while Task ends

Tags: wpf, listbox, freeze

How to freeze a `ListBox` until a `Thread` ends to prevent `SelectedIndex` highlight loss ?

Here is my actual code (but Selection highlight is lost when i disable and enable the ListBox):

```
        ListBox_DeviceList.IsEnabled = false;


        if (ListBox_DeviceList.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            bool error = await GetAvailableJobs();

            //enables when Task ends ...
            ListBox_DeviceList.IsEnabled = true;

            if (error)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to set the Enable property (you used .IsEnabled) to false, and at the end, set to true.

```
ListBox_DeviceList.Enabled = false;


    if (ListBox_DeviceList.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        bool error = await GetAvailableJobs();

        //enables when Task ends ...
        ListBox_DeviceList.Enabled = true;

        if (error)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Other way, is call SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() methods.

```
ListBox_DeviceList.SuspendLayout();


    if (ListBox_DeviceList.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        bool error = await GetAvailableJobs();

        //enables when Task ends ...
        ListBox_DeviceList.ResumeLayout();

        if (error)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: hello! thanks for answer but property `Enabled` does not exist on WPF ... my solution was set `this.IsEnabled = false;` while `Task` is completed and override  `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey` and `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey` of `ListBox` on XML to simulate active highlight colors when is disabled ...